# Organic Groups manage members for all but one group role

Tags: organic-groups

I have a site that I'm building and planning to use OG to manage access to some content.  There is a requirement for an OG role that is the can manage all memberships, except for one role.  The use case is that the group owners want to delegate membership management in most cases but don't want to allow one of these group admin helpers to be able to change the owners role.  Manage members doesn't provide enough granularity for this.  Any suggestions on how to approach it?